# Adding a factor from another factor

Tags: r, factors

I have 5 dichotomous variables (0=no and 1=yes). Selecting 'yes' indicates that a subject stated this behavior is a part of their coping skills (e.g., meditation; going for a walk). I have summed the coping skills variable and then created a factor (0 skills used; 1-2 skills used; 3 or more skills used).

```
levels(x$var1)
[1] "0"  "1"
```

Total coping skills factor variable:

```
x %>% count(cop.skills)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  str.12     n
  <fct>  <int>
1 0       3743
2 1-2     4398
3 3+      2632
```

There's a sixth dichotomous variable asking, "I have never done any of these behaviors (listed above)," with a dichotomous answer (0=no and 1=yes).

```
 x %>% count(var6)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  stress2     n
  <fct>   <int>
1 0       11456
2 1          77
```

I would like to add the "yeses" to the "0" level of cop.skills variable. "cop.skills" would look like this:

```
x %>% count(cop.skills)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  str.12     n
  <fct>  <int>
1 0       3820
2 1-2     4398
3 3+      2632
```

Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add them to your first result?

```r
result    <- x %>% count(cop.skills)
no_skills <- x %>% count(var6)
result[1, 2] <- result[1, 2] + no_skills[2, 2]
```

Comment: I get an error:

```
result[1, 2] <- result[1, 2] + no_skills [2, 2]
Error in `[.default`(result, 1, 2) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: there must be a problem with `result` then - what does it look like?

Comment: It looks like:
```
> result
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cop.skills     n
  <fct>         <int>
1 0              3734
2 1-2           4568
3 3+            2312
```

Comment: So if you type result[1,2] you should get 3734? and what does no_skills[2,2] give? I take it you haven't accidentally put the space in between no_skills and the square bracket like you did in your comment?

Comment: Ok. Yes! It did work thanks. How would I be able to recode this into another variable of my data frame? For example, my data is x, I would like result be x$result.

Comment: The problem is that `x` is a dataframe with one row for each observation, so it doesn't make much sense to append these results to your data frame. If you want data and results together in a single data structure you could make a list like this: `experiment <- list(data = x, results = results)`. Now you can see your data with experiment$data and your results as experiment$results.